# Terraform Multiple Versions of Same Provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm having hard time working with modules of multiple versions, i even tried using Alias but its not working. Here's an sample code. Can someone suggest where i'm doing wrong? or what's the correct way.

```
providers = {
   azurerm = azurerm
   azurerm.permission = azurerm.permission
}


terraform {
  required_providers {
  azurerm = {
    source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    version         = "~> 2.76.0"
  }
  azurerm = {
    source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    version         = "~> 3.7.0"
    configuration_aliases = [azurerm.permission]
  }

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = data.vault_generic_secret.vault-spoke-spn.data["subscription_id"]
  tenant_id       = data.vault_generic_secret.vault-spoke-spn.data["tenant_id"]
  client_id       = data.vault_generic_secret.vault-spoke-spn.data["client_id"]
  client_secret   = data.vault_generic_secret.vault-spoke-spn.data["client_secret"]
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias = "permission"
  subscription_id = data.vault_generic_secret.vault-spoke-spn.data["subscription_id"]
  tenant_id       = data.vault_generic_secret.vault-spoke-spn.data["tenant_id"]
  client_id       = data.vault_generic_secret.vault-spoke-spn.data["client_id"]
  client_secret   = data.vault_generic_secret.vault-spoke-spn.data["client_secret"]
}
```

Comment: "but its not working" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: There is no way to use multiple versions of the same provider in the same configuration. You will need to either make all of your modules have some provider version they are all mutually compatible with, or to split your configuration into multiple parts so that each part can depend on a different version of the provider and be applied separately.

Comment: As Martin said is correct. for more information you can check out this document : https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers

Answer (score 1):

Thank You [Martin Atkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins) for your suggestion. Adding few more points and referennce that might help other community member.

> There is no way to use multiple versions of the same provider in the
> same configuration. You will need to either make all of your modules
> have some provider version they are all mutually compatible with, or
> to split your configuration into multiple parts so that each part can
> depend on a different version of the provider and be applied
> separately.

Inheritance and the providers argument in a module block are the two methods that providers can be explicitly passed down to successor modules. you can follow this [***link***](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers)  go into greater depth about these two choices.

Comment: Why are you taking someone else's comment and turning it into your own answer? They could have done that themselves, if there was indeed a need for an answer, vs "you can't do it". Note that the person who posted the comment has a fairly high rep and is not new to this site and its guidelines.